# multiple image uploads in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, image, file-upload

If I have situation like below, where I success. handle image upload and store in db. Having this code in mind how would you implement multiple image upload.
Thank you.

So first thing first.

```
PropertyViewModel.cs

...
public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }

public PropertyViewModel(Property x)
{
  ....
  ImageData = x.ImageData;
  ImageMimeType = x.ImageMimeType;
}

public void ToDomainModel(Property x)
{
  ....
  x.ImageData = ImageData;
  x.ImageMimeType = ImageMimeType;
}
```

Now form Create.cshtml razor page

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Property", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  ...
   <input type="file" name="Image"/>
}
```

}

Controller to handle request

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PropertyViewModel newProperty, HttpPostedFileBase image)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (image != null)
                {
                    newProperty.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
                    newProperty.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];

                    image.InputStream.Read(newProperty.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength);
                }
                using (session...)
                {
                    using (...begin transaction)
                    {
                        MyDomain.Property model = new MyDomain.Property();
                        newProperty.ToDomainModel(model);
                        ..session save model
                        .. commiting session
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(newProperty);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Property", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ...
    <input type="file" name="Image"/>
    <input type="file" name="Image"/>
    <input type="file" name="Image"/>
    <input type="file" name="Image"/>
}
```

or if the browser supports HTML5 you could select multiple files in the upload dialog:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Property", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ...
    <input type="file" name="Image" multiple="multiple"/>
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Create(PropertyViewModel newProperty, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> image)
```

Comment: thank you thats great. How would you implement edit action with this viewmodel in mind. To load all images based on some id on edit action. Thank you

Comment: I would add an `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Image { get; set; }` property directly into the view model and get rid of the second action argument.

Comment: Do I then need to alter domain Property. Now its 
---------
public virtual byte[] ImageData
        {
            get { return _ImageData; }
            set
            {
                if (_ImageData == value)
                    return;
                _ImageData = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual string ImageMimeType
        {
            get { return _ImageMimeType; }
            set
            {
                if (_ImageMimeType == value)
                    return;
                _ImageMimeType = value;
            }    
        }